# Default random engine as class member, even if passed by reference does not update external engine

Tags: c++, random, pass-by-reference, class-members

I know that I have to pass the random engine by reference in order for it to update out of a function. However, if I pass it by reference in a class construction, it looks like the seed is not changing outside of the class.

Minimum working example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<random>

class rv{
        public: 
        std::default_random_engine rv_eng;
        rv(std::default_random_engine & eng){
                this->rv_eng = eng;
        }
        double nd(){
                std::normal_distribution<double> ndist {0.0, 1.0};
                double draw = ndist(this->rv_eng);
                return draw;
        }
};

int main(){
        std::default_random_engine main_engine;
        main_engine.seed(123);
        std::cout << main_engine << std::endl;
        rv rv_instance(main_engine);
        std::cout << rv_instance.nd() << std::endl;
        std::cout << main_engine << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

The result I get is

```
123
-0.331232
123
```

While I would have expected the second generator to change. Why is it the same?

Comment: The member in the class is not a reference so there is no link to the outside object. https://godbolt.org/z/MEzzdqMjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like someone else already suggested; use an initializer list, that way you can have a reference variable as a member:

```
class rv
{
public:
    std::default_random_engine& eng_ref;
    rv(std::default_random_engine& eng) : eng_ref{ eng } {};
    double nd()
    {
        std::normal_distribution<double> ndist {0.0, 1.0};
        double draw = ndist(eng_ref);
        return draw;
    }
};
```